RFC of the Postal Analogy
Is there an informational RFC which describes the Postal Analogy used to explain layered reference models of network protocols?

There are multiple RFCs that cover network layers. Just search for rfc layer.

The base RFCs for Internet Protocol layering are 1122 and 1123 with their updates.
The postal analogy is not from any IETF RFC but used in various sources, e.g. in the TCP/IP Guide.

Thank for the solution.
